# Custom update actions in RESTful Services

Tags: node.js, rest

My API requires many different types of updates that can be performed by different types of roles. A ticket can have it's data updated, a ticket can be approved (which includes some information), a ticket can be rejected, a ticket can be archived (state that makes a ticket unable to be updated), etc.

I've recently started working as a backend developer and I really do not know what is the most correct approach to this situation but I've two ideas in mind:

- A single update endpoint (e.g. `/api/tickets/:id`) that accepts an action field with the type of update that wants to be done to that file;
- Multiple custom action endpoints (e.g. `/api/tickets/:id/validate`, `/api/tickets/:id/accept`, etc.)

Which one of those is the best approach to the situation when it comes to the REST architecture? If both are incorrect when it comes to REST, what would be the most correct approach? I couldn't really find any post on SO that answered my question so I decided to create my own. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

REST is all about *resources*. And the state of the resources should be manipulated using representations (such as JSON, XML, you name it) on the top of stateless communication between client and server.

Once URIs are meant to identify the resources, it makes sense to use *nouns* instead of *verbs* in the URI. And when designing a REST API over the HTTP protocol, HTTP methods should be used to indicate the action intended to be performed over the resource.

### Performing partial updates

You could use the [`PATCH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) HTTP verb to perform partial updates to your resource. The [`PATCH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) request payload must contain set of changes to applied to the resource.

There are a couple of formats that can be used to describe the set of changes to be applied to the resource:

###JSON Merge Patch

It's defined in the [RFC 7396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396) and can be applied as described below:

> If the provided merge patch contains members that do not appear within the target, those members are added.  If the target does contain the member, the value is replaced. Null values in the merge patch are given special meaning to indicate the removal of existing values in the target.

So a request to modify the `status` of a ticket could be like:

```
PATCH /api/tickets/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json

{
  "status": "valid"
}
```

###JSON Patch

It's defined in the [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) and expresses a sequence of operations to be applies to a target JSON document. A request to modify the `status` of a ticket could be like:

```
PATCH /api/tickets/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/status",
    "value": "valid"
  }
]
```

The `path` is a JSON Pointer value, as described in the [RFC 6901](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901).

Answer (score 2):

REST stands for Representational State Transfer, which means that the client and the server affect each other’s state by exchanging *representations* of resources.

A client might `GET` a representation of a ticket like this:

```
GET /api/tickets/123 HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "id": 123, 
    "state": "new",
    "archived": false,
    "comments": []
}
```

Now the client can [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) a new representation (replacing it wholesale) or [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) specific parts of the existing one:

```
PATCH /api/tickets/123 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
    {"op": "replace", "path": "/state", "value": "approved"},
    {"op": "add", "path": "/comments", "value": {
        "text": "Looks good to me!"
    }}
]


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "id": 123,
    "state": "approved",
    "archived": false,
    "comments": [
        {"author": "Thomas", "text": "Looks good to me!"}
    ]
}
```

Note how the update is expressed in terms of *what is to be changed in the JSON representation*, using the standard [JSON Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) format. The client could use the same approach to update *any* resource represented in JSON. This contributes to a [uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5), decoupling the client from the specific server.

Of course, the server need not support arbitrary updates:

```
PATCH /api/tickets/123 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
    {"op": "replace", "path": "/id", "value": 456}
]


HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
Content-Type: text/plain

Cannot replace /id.
```

Still, this might require more complexity on the server than dedicated operations like “approve”, “reject”, etc. You might want to use [a library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-json-patch) to implement JSON Patch. If you find that you need many custom actions which are hard to express in terms of a representation, an RPC architecture might suit you better than REST.

Answer (score 1):

Try to either

- Deal with a single object -> `api/v1/tickets/1`
- Deal with a list of objects -> `api/v1/tickets/`.

Then try to capture all actions as CRUD actions.

- Create object(s) -> `HTTP POST`
- Retreive object(s) -> `HTTP GET`
- Update object(s) -> `HTTP PATCH`
- Delete object(s) -> `HTTP DELETE`

And also:

- Save object(s) entirely -> `HTTP PUT`

When you are changing statuses, and these are just attributes on a ticket. I would send a `PATCH` request, for instance. If I need to change the statues of ticket #1 to "rejected" I would send something like `PATCH` `api/v1/tickets/1` with a payload like:

```
{
    "status": "rejected"
}
```

REST has a lot of best practices but not everything is set in stone. Maybe this tutorial: https://restfulapi.net can help you?

Answer (score 1):

Really it all comes down to a matter of taste. It is often observed in the industry to have the **static parameters in the URL** (eg: `/tickets/update`, `/users/add`, `/admin/accounts`) and the **variable parameters in the query** (eg: IDs, messages, names). It allows to have a fixed number of endpoints.

I see you're using NodeJS so you're probably using Express and in Express getting the url parameters and the body parameters are equally easy:

```
// supposing you're using a JSON-based API with body-parser for JSON parsing
app.get('/some/path/:someParam', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.someParam);
    console.log(req.body.someOtherParam);
    res.send();
}
```